# Error in executing a Jar file in remote machine

Tags: java, ssh, jar

I am trying to executing a `jar file` which is present in remote machine. When I execute below command from my local machine I get error:

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/pem_file user@[host_ip]:/home/user/folder1/java -cp jar1.jar -a option1 -e user1@gmail.com -f TextFile.txt
```

`/home/user/folder1/` is the location where `jar file` is present on remote machine.The error I get is:

```
Unknown cipher type 'p'
```

I then looked up for this error and found out the with `ssh` we may not need it. So, I removed -cp from it and executed this command:

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/pem_file user@[host_ip]:/home/user/folder1/java jar1.jar -a option1 -e user1@gmail.com -f TextFile.txt
```

Now I get error as:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname [host name]:/home/user/folder1/java: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Do you have to connect via `ssh` and run the `jar` all in one line of code?

Comment: when you say `[host_ip]` are you enclosing the `host_ip` in literal brackets (`[ ]`)?

Comment: @JonnyHenly no I am not enclosing the ip in `[ ]`. I have just shown it that way in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command should be passed to `ssh` after hostname separated by space not colon, like this:

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/pem_file user@[host_ip] /home/user/folder1/java -cp jar1.jar -a option1 -e user1@gmail.com -f TextFile.txt
```

If you have parts in the command that could be parsed by your local shell before sent to remote host (for example `cd /tmp && ls` or `cat /file | uniq > some.log`) it should be enclosed in single quotes:

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/pem_file user@[host_ip] 'cd /home/user/folder1 && java -jar jar1.jar -a option1 -e user1@gmail.com -f TextFile.txt'
```

Comment: @JonnyHenly No, it's not always required. Just try to execute `ssh example.com java -version`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly which part of the command should be surrounded with quotes?

Comment: Not required but it is good practice, especially if you are running more than one command.

Comment: @user2966197 `ssh -i /root/.ssh/pem_file user@[host_ip] '/home/user/folder1/java jar1.jar -a option1 -e user1@gmail.com -f TextFile.txt'`  use single quotes (`'`) not double quotes (`"`).

Comment: @JonnyHenly when I execute the command your way I get `bash: /home/user/folder1/java: No such file or directory`

Comment: @user2966197 I think you don't have `java` executable in specified folder, could you try the second example from my answer?

Comment: @user2966197 I thought you might, `cd` to the directory before running the java command.

Comment: And I've updated my answer again: @user2966197 as you don't have classname specified, probably what you want is a `-jar` option (it will run main class from the jar file), not `-cp` (it just sets a classpath).

Comment: I executed the updated code with -jar and I got `Error: Unable to access jarfile jar1.jar`

Comment: So there's no `jar1.jar` file in the folder `/home/user/folder1`, but I don't think it's related to your original question about ssh command and without additional info (like, what are you trying to do here?) it's hard to help you, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a executable jar?

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/pem_file user@[host_ip] 'java -jar jar1.jar -a option1 -e user1@gmail.com -f TextFile.txt'
```

Otherwise, follow `-cp` with the main class:

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/pem_file user@[host_ip] 'java -cp jar1.jar full.package.name.ClassName -a option1 -e user1@gmail.com -f TextFile.txt'
```