# Error in executing .jar file from a Python script called from another Python script, as a subprocess

Tags: java, python, jar, subprocess

This is in extension to a resolved post that I had posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766563/error-in-executing-a-jar-file-in-remote-machine). I have a `python script` which has the following `jar` execution code in it(alongwith some other codes):

**python_file2.py**

```
import os
cmd_txt = "ssh -i pem_file.pem user@" + host_name + " 'cd /user/folder1/ && java -cp jar-file.jar'"
os.system(cmd_txt)
```

Now this `python script` file(python_file2.py) is called as a `subprocess` from another `python script`.

**Main_script.py**

```
ret = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"python_file2.py"])
```

When I run this **Main_script.py** then the execution of the `jar` file from `python_file2.py` seems to get hanged. When I run the first script alone it works fine but when I try to execute it as `subprocess` then the `jar` execution hangs and timeouts.

What could be a possible reason for this `jar` execution getting hanged when executed from inside a `subprocess` script? All I want to is run a jar file which is present on remote machine from inside a python script which is ran as a `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.Popen`:

```
ret = subprocess.call([sys.executable,"python_file2.py"])
assert not ret, ret
```

Comment: what difference does `subprocess.call` provides from `subprocess.Popen` that may result in this behaviour?

Comment: If I am correct `subprocess.call` in turn makes a call to `subprocess.Popen`  right?

Comment: could anyone point me to what difference does `subprocess.call` provides from `subprocess.Popen` that may be result in resolving the issue?